# Equivalent of scipy.signal.lfilter in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, filter, scipy

Is there any replacement of the following in python?

```
from scipy import signal

scipy.signal.lfilter()
```

and may i get the same result of above from any numpy command?

Comment: Answer is probably no, but if it is just a matter of avoiding installing scipy you can always try and copy the [source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.1/scipy/signal/signaltools.py#L858-L1041). You'll have to check for dependencies, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `numpy.convolve` if you are using a simple FIR filter, because in that case `b=window`, `a=1` in terms of the `lfilter` args. The edge effects might be a little different though. You would probably want to use `mode='same'`  for the `convolve` function.